Leaflet Map Tiles Disappear When Panning – Tiles Reappear on Movement
I'm experiencing an issue with my web app using Leaflet for map rendering. As I move around the map, tiles disappear, and they only reappear when I pan to another part of the map. This creates a flickering effect where tiles vanish and reappear depending on my movement.
Expected behavior: All map tiles should remain visible as I pan around.
What I’ve tried:
Checked the tile layer settings to ensure tiles are being loaded properly.
Verified the map bounds and zoom settings to see if they affect tile visibility.
Looked into whether it might be an issue with the map's rendering or tile loading, but haven't found a solution.
Environment:
Leaflet version: 1.9.4
Browser: Brave, Chrome (everywhere is the same)
Code example:


@Component({
   selector: 'app-sa-map',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [],
   templateUrl: './sa-map.component.html',
   styleUrl: './sa-map.component.scss',
})
export class SaMapComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() width: string = '400px';
   @Input() height: string = '400px';

   private static mapExtent = [1022.5, 1022.5, 1022.5, 1022.5];
   private static mapZoom = { min: 0, max: 3 };
   private static mapMaxResolution = 1;
   private static mapMinResolution = Math.pow(2, SaMapComponent.mapZoom.max) * SaMapComponent.mapMaxResolution;

   private crs: L.CRS | undefined;
   private map: L.Map | undefined;
   private layer: L.Layer | undefined;

   initializeMap() {
      this.crs = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
         transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0),

         scale: function(zoom: number) {
            return Math.pow(2, zoom) / SaMapComponent.mapMinResolution;
         },

         zoom: function(scale: number) {
            return Math.log(scale * SaMapComponent.mapMinResolution) / Math.LN2;
         },
      });

      this.map = L.map('map', {
         maxZoom: SaMapComponent.mapZoom.max,
         minZoom: SaMapComponent.mapZoom.min,
         crs: this.crs,
      });

      this.layer = L.tileLayer(`${environment.staticUrl}/images/tiles/sat.{z}.{x}.{y}.png`, {
         minZoom: SaMapComponent.mapZoom.min,
         maxZoom: SaMapComponent.mapZoom.max,
         noWrap: true,
         tms: false,
      }).addTo(this.map);

      const element = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-attribution');
      (<HTMLElement>element[0]).style.display = 'none';

      this.map!.fitBounds([
         this.crs!.unproject(L.point(SaMapComponent.mapExtent[2], SaMapComponent.mapExtent[3])) as unknown as LatLngTuple,
         this.crs!.unproject(L.point(SaMapComponent.mapExtent[0], SaMapComponent.mapExtent[1])) as unknown as LatLngTuple,
      ]);

      // this.map!.fitBounds([
      //    [SaMapComponent.mapExtent[2], SaMapComponent.mapExtent[3]],
      //    [SaMapComponent.mapExtent[0], SaMapComponent.mapExtent[1]]
      // ])
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.initializeMap();
   }

   mirrorNumbers(min: number, max: number, num: number) {
      let j = (max - num) - (num - min);
      return num + j;
   }

   reverseMirrorNumbers(min: number, max: number, mirroredNum: number) {
      return (max + min - mirroredNum);
   }

   private gameToMapCoords(x: number, y: number) {
      const mapSideLength = 2045.0;
      const topLeftX = -2990.0;
      const topLeftY = 3000.0;

      x = this.mirrorNumbers(0.0, mapSideLength, (x / topLeftX) * mapSideLength) / 2.0;
      y = this.mirrorNumbers(0.0, mapSideLength, (y / topLeftY) * mapSideLength) / 2.0;

      return { x, y };
   }

   mapToGameCoords(mapX: number, mapY: number) {
      const mapSideLength = 2045.0;
      const topLeftX = -2990.0;
      const topLeftY = 3000.0;

      let x = mapX * 2.0;
      let y = mapY * 2.0;

      x = this.reverseMirrorNumbers(0.0, mapSideLength, x);
      y = this.reverseMirrorNumbers(0.0, mapSideLength, y);

      x = (x / mapSideLength) * topLeftX;
      y = (y / mapSideLength) * topLeftY;

      return { x, y };
   }

   addToMap(x: number, y: number) {
      const mapCoords = this.gameToMapCoords(x, y);
      x = mapCoords.x;
      y = mapCoords.y;

      L.marker([y, x]).addTo(this.map!);
   }
}


I think you forgot to import CSS file. Try to import leaflet/dist/leaflet.css in your global styles.

Hard to say with little details and no [mcve]. Could be improper transformation: if you display a bigger map port, are tiles correctly assembled? Might also be just slow loading.
